# Forward slash got mapped to Oo in vim

Tags: vim

I dont know how but forward slash is mapped to Oo(behavior similar to Shift-o o in normal mode) in vim hence I cannot search. I tried to start vim with --noplugin but the problem still persists. The result of

```
:verbose map /
```

is blank. Here is my vimrc file(http://pastebin.com/cUJTaxFm)

The problem is caused by the last line of my vimrc but I dont know how.

**UPD**: even after removing the last line and loading vim with --noplugin with no local vimrc the problem again surfaced back. I cannot even do `:verbose map /` because `/` gets expanded to `Shift-o o` even here. Whenever I press `/` I only get o in my screen in any mode. `/` key is working properly in gedit. I dont know how to debug this please help.

Comment: Don't map escape. It will lead to unpredictable behavior. The way the terminal communicates with programs is using escape sequences. For example the the arrow keys are mapped to `<esc>OA`, `<esc>OB`, `<esc>OC`, and `<esc>OD`. If you make escape a `<nop>` you will still get the `OA` which is not what you expect. I don't know why `/` generates `Oo` though.

Comment: Typing "`:map /`" and pressing enter should show you all mappings starting with a slash.